# Не отображаются данные в виджете Android

Tags: java, android, kotlin, api, виджет

Проблема следующая - запрашиваю данные через ретрофит в openweathermap API. Возвращаю их в виджет. В виджет они приходят, но не отображаются. И, в целом, вьюха вообще не обновляется в подписке. А если вне подписки обновлять, то всё обновляется и данные отображаются в виджете. Почему так? Я же обновляю вью в виджете в в мэйн потоке (.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())).

```
val views = RemoteViews(context.packageName, R.layout.weather_widget)

        WeatherRepository().getWeather(actualCity)
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(
                        { newsList ->
                            Toast.makeText(context, "asdsadasd", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                            Log.i("FFFF", newsList.city.country)
                            views.setTextViewText(R.id.countryWidget, "newsList.city.name.toString()")
                            views.setTextViewText(R.id.currentData, newsList.list[0].dt_txt)
                            views.setTextViewText(R.id.degreesWidget, newsList.list[0].main.temp.toInt().toString())
                        },
                        { error -> Toast.makeText(context, "Widget Weather ERROR: $error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()


                        }
                ).apply { /*compositeDisposable.add(this) */}
```

Answer (score 0):

Проблему решил. Я запрашивал данные в подписке, а вызывал update ниже, в итоге - update отрабатывал быстрее, чем приходили данные.